# What are the best practices for secure login in PHP web application?

Tags: php, security, session, authentication

I would like some clarification on what are some best practices for secure web  login and, further, persistent login for a PHP application that is authenticating against Active Directory.

1. At login, does it make sense to implement a Post-Redirect-Get model? Storing the password in `$_SESSION` probably isn't a good idea.
2. After authentication, is checking if a specific `$_SESSION` field is set a valid and secure way to check if a user is logged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is NOT a good idea to store the password in plain text at any point in time.

1) I do not recommend the PRG model for a login page.  The worst thing that could happen is that the person is logged in twice.  That's not so bad.

Data stored in $_SESSION can typically not be read by the client.  They ARE stored on the server where a malicious employee or hacker might get access to them.

2) After authentication it is ok to check the session to see if someone is logged in.  Someone may spoof someone else's session id but the chance of that is minimal as long as you are running SSL.  I recommend storing the IP, user agent, and other information you can get easily in the $_SERVER variable and comparing it either on occasion or every time. To reduce the chance that someone has hacked the other person's session id.

Regenerating a session id on login doesn't make a lot of sense to me, although I don't know your particular scenario.  My suggestion is to simply regenerate it on log out.  Also, you can add a time out feature to the session if you like.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I was thinking about the PRG model based on the fact that if a user clicks on something, then uses the back button on the browser, it barks about needing to re-post the information. I suppose I could auth then redirect, though.

Comment: session id regeneration is used to prevent user from using a session id that was used upon HTTP in non-logged mode. Now that he's logged in it's important that he runs over SSL with a session ID which is not the same as before, else the SSL mode won't protect anything new.

Comment: @regilero - That makes sense.  Although, if you're going to have SSL on your site, why not always use it?  I've seen a lot more problems switching back and forth between SSL and non-SSL than I've seen issues/lag from constant SSL.

Comment: that makes sens as well :-) it depends on the number of connected session vs anonymous sessions and your proxy-cache & ssl handling (load balancers, ssl session sharing, etc), can be problems of traffic as well. But I saw recently on SO a link about the SSL generalisation for google websites, sur it will make more sense in the coming days.

Answer (score 1):

You should only store something to differentiate anonymous users and logged in users, like a is_valid keyword in the session.

This mean that anybody catching the session id (which is a cookie value sent in clear at each request) would get the session. This is called session **hijacking** and is now the only thing you should fear.

The way to protect you against this is to handle all connected-users pages in HTTPS while they're logged in... or to prey that noeone will make an XSS attack or will hack your user wifi hotspot to get the session id.

Well, in fact they're several other ways like storing some sort of signature of the client browser (user-agent, maybe the IP-can be problematic with moving proxies, list of intalled plugins, etc), and make a nice hash of that. Store it in the cookie and check it sometimes. **Edit:** you can check my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841428/effective-methods-of-indentifying-and-blacklisting-a-user/5841590#5841590) as well on some ways to track & identify one user browser, can be used to ensure the session is still used by the same user.

**Never** store the password in the session file, never store the password nowhere.